# How to apply a domain to a button?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I want to pass a *default* domain from a button to be applied to a target action.
Something like this:

```
<!-- action -->
<act_window id="action_target"
            name="Project Categories"
            res_model="addon.model"
            view_mode="kanban,tree,form"/>

<!-- button -->
<button class="btn btn-primary"
        type="action"
        name="%(action_target)d"
        domain="[('field_x', '=', self.id)]">
  Do Something
</button>
```

The way I'm doing it right now is by triggering a function that opens a new action window:

```
@api.multi
def action_target(self):
  self.ensure_one()
  return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'src_model': self._name,
    'res_model': 'addon.model',
    'view_mode': 'kanban,tree,form',
    'domain': [('field_x', '=', self.id)],
    'target': 'main',
  }
```

The unwanted behavior that comes with the way I'm doing it is that is does not keep the path to the previous window like action button does:

[image]

I want it stay like:

[image]

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want to do exactly, but here we go :

**If you want to open another view showing all records where field_x = self.id**

Use `'search_default_field_x': self.id` in the context in your action. This should open your view with a search set, looking for every record where `field_x` is equal to `self.id`. You probably need to define a search view able to search on `field_x` for this to work (`default` won't fill a field if it's not in the view).

I think this answers the question in your title and the first part of your question.

**If you don't want to break the breadcrumbs :**

Based on [odoo 10.0 documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/actions.html) :

> **Window Actions (ir.actions.act_window)**
>
> target (optional) whether the views should be open in the main content
>   area (current), in full screen mode (fullscreen) or in a dialog/popup
>   (new). Use **main instead of current to clear the breadcrumbs**. Defaults
>   to current.

So, try to use `current` instead of `new` and it should do what you want to do. At least, it works in some code I wrote for my company, but this is for odoo 8. Since this is the default, this is why it works in your first snippet.

Answer (score 1):

you should try following.

```
<record id="action_target" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Project Categories</field>
    <field name="res_model">addon.model</field>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
    <field name="context">{
        'search_default_field_x': [active_id],
        'default_field_x': active_id,
        }
    </field>
</record>
```

> You can set default search values using context in action. For more
>   details refer project module and in project module refer "Tasks"
>   button. It's the same which you want to do here.